# Easy way to create my output stream and keep with with a specific format in C++?

Tags: c++, output-formatting

There are several ways to do this (I believe). But I simply want a stream that will get all my data and output it to console. I tried using a `stringstream` by setting the `strinstream::out` flag and then doing a `cout` on the `str()` member function, but it didn't work as I expected.

Example:

```
somestream myS;
myS.flags(ios::left);
myS<<data<<data<<data<<endl;
```

This will either automatically output to console or I will have to do it manually (Somehow). The data will always be formatted to what I set.

P.s.: I can't use printf, or boost.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Show a short example of code that doesn't work, and explain what you want different.

Comment: Do you want to do `std::cout << myType` with specific formatting? What is your question?

Comment: Jesse: Not specifically. I want it to go to the console.

Comment: Like [this](http://ideone.com/Jn7mN)?

Comment: This is what I already tried. What about the formatting on it staying the same for all the program? Like width.

Comment: `std::cout.width(**Put width here**);`

Answer (score 0):

sprintf is useful for printing out strings/null terminated strings in a useful fashion. Its old but it works. It can take variable arguments and the like.
[Sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)(sprintf)

Comment: I actually said by the end that I couldn't use printf (Or any variations, for that matter). Still, thanks.